# Is using std::max for comparing two doubles safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know for comparing two doubles we have to do something like this

```
bool AreSame(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}
```

But I do not know that does std::max compares two doubles the same way or if not the same way safely? That is what will be the answer if I call
`std::max(0.1,0.11)`  . I am getting right results but still , I am not sure!
Morover I used it last night at codeforces and got my solution accepted!

Why am I worried?
I checked http://www.cplusplus.com/ were it was written that the behaviour of max is same as the following code

```
template <class T> const T& max (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return (a<b)?b:a;     // or: return comp(a,b)?b:a; for version (2)
}
```

The link to page [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)

(The relative difference being 10^-6)

Comment: I don't think there's anywhere near as much error when comparing using `<` compared to `==`. `std::max` should be safe for values as far apart as 0.1 and 0.11. If there was an error, it'd only be when the two values are nearly identical anyways and the result is unlikely to matter that much.

Comment: `fabs(a - b) < EPSILON;` isn't reliable in general: large values of `a` and/or `b` need a large `EPSILON`, while two small values need a small `EPSILON`.  How to do it properly is undoubtedly asked and answered elsewhere on S.O....

Comment: I don't think they'd create a specialization of `std::max` for `double` if it weren't safe.  If they had, there'd probably be big caveats/warnings about its use.

Comment: Your worries seem to be misplaced. "Floating point" doesn't mean "you should use epsilons everywhere". Read the "**What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic**" paper that's mentioned everywhere, and has multiple mirrors all over the internet.

Comment: Yeah! I figured it out ! I read it wrong from my book!

Comment: @BrianCain: It's not a specialization, just a regular instantiation. (At least according to the Standard). As for " safety", `std::count(begin, end, 3.0/10.0);` has bigger issues yet that's perfectly legal C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(as you just amended to your question) max should be doing a simple '<', like

```
(a < b) ? b : a
```

This should be "safe" in that you can do a comparison between two doubles/floats.  However, doubles/floats are really just approximations for values, they may or may not be the exact value.  You can see this in base 10 with a value like 1/3 = .3333...  the written decimal value can never be exact 1/3 because it is an infinitely repeating value.  In order for the processor to work with discrete values a limited number of bits must be used, therefore rounding will occur.  This makes the concept of "equals" a bit muddy, really are you saying two values are approximately equal, close enough given some tolerance (epsilon).  You can argue that > and < are also effected by the vagaries of this approximation process.  However, generally people are willing to accept the "broader" idea of two values having a < or > relationship.

It can actually be a quite complicated question.  It depends largely on what you are doing and the sort of tolerance your application has to these numeric approximation issues.  I know of one case where an AI algorithm was affected by a change from using FPU instructions to using MMX/SSE/AVX... type instructions (PC FPUs generally calculate internally at 80 bits then round, while AVX instructions use 64 bits [stem to stern](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stem+to+stern)).  Over the course of many iterations differences based on rounding caused different paths to be taken leading to different results.  This largely had to do with these types of comparisons.  You can't say that the approach (depending on FPU behavior) was incorrect, only that it wasn't tolerant of changes to a "lower resolution" FP calculation.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the the choice of `(a<b)?b:a` is not arbitrary, as it will behave differently from the almost equivalent `(b>a)?b:a` when one of the operands is a `NaN` The first gives `max(NaN, 1.0)=NaN`  but the second gives `max(NaN,1.0)=1`

Comment: So if i compare 3.145551 with 3.145552 the answer will be correct always(The relative difference being 10^{-6} ) ? I was totally living in the dark believing we cannot compare inequalities even! that is we cannot check double values with < , > . May be I didn't read it nicely in my c++ book. Morover I would like to tell you I am comparing values in decimals (Not non terminating numbers like 22/7)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: what about `max(1.0, NaN)`? The IEEE 754-2008 standard says that, specifically for maximum and minimum functions, NaN means "missing data", so it should always return the non-NaN argument. That's how [`std::fmax()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmax) behaves (if IEC 60559 is supported).

Comment: @Ishu  Yes if you compare  3.145551 with 3.145552, this will work for both float (32 bit) and double (64 bit), but if those were >7 digit values, you would be beyond the precision of floats, this can cause rounding which might lead to unexpected results

Answer (score 3):

`std::max` isn't concerned with equality, it only cares when the two numbers are not equal. Additionally the epsilon thing is related to looking for approximately equal numbers whose difference is caused by floating point errors. Floating point errors should cause `std::max` to pick one over the other as `std::max` has no way of knowing what epsilon would be appropriate.

Remember your system may want `AreSame(0.1000001, 0.1) == true` but `std::max(0.1000001, 0.1)` should return `0.1000001` in case you do care.